# Icon added with input-group-append seems bigger then input box

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have got the following search input box within a navbar.

[image]

The thing that confuses me is that the appended search icon looks as if its bigger then the input search field. This seems to be due the "inline" shadow used within the search box.

How can make the icon look *better* without having to remove the shadow?

```
<nav>
    <!-- removed -->

    <!-- Right side items -->
    <form class="navbar-nav form-inline flex-column flex-sm-row" style="flex-basis: 350px;">
      <div class="input-group flex-sm-fill">
        <input class="form-control" id="search-box" type="search" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card shadow px-4 border-top-0" id="result-box" style="display: none; position: absolute; top: 46px;">
          <ul class="list-unstyled" id="search-result"></ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/gungorbudak/pen/ooKNpz

Comment: Can't reproduce it: https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/tgbfh50p/3/